# How to hide equation number with using align

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath

I wrote the following to print a mathematical equation, but I do not need the number of equation to be appeared:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
f_{n}(\beta,\lambda)&= \lambda(1-\lambda/n)^{n-1} \int_{0} ^{1} g_{n}(\beta,\lambda)d\alpha \\
                     & \leq \lambda(1-\lambda/n)^{n-1}\int_{0}^{1} g_{n}(\beta,1)d\alpha \\
                     & \leq (1-1/n)^{n-1} \int_{0}^{1} g_{n}(\beta,1)d\alpha = f_{n}(\beta,1)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{align*}....\end{align*}` -- A `*` most times indicates suppression of numbering

Comment: Try `align*` and see

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Either use `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}` or use `\nonumber` for a specific equation to be suppressed in an `align` environment.

This might get tedious if all equations in an `align` environment should be unnumbered.

General rule: An environment or command with `*` most times means: 'Do not number'

The same is true for `alignat` and `alignat*` environments and `equation` and `equation*` environments from `amsmath`, the later two are for a single equation only.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
f_{n}(\beta,\lambda)&= \lambda(1-\lambda/n)^{n-1} \int_{0} ^{1} g_{n}(\beta,\lambda)d\alpha \nonumber \\
                     & \leq \lambda(1-\lambda/n)^{n-1}\int_{0}^{1} g_{n}(\beta,1)d\alpha \\
                     & \leq (1-1/n)^{n-1} \int_{0}^{1} g_{n}(\beta,1)d\alpha = f_{n}(\beta,1)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\nonumber` doens't only hide, but doesn't count the line either. Is there a way to just hide the number on a specific line, but still count it?

Comment: @mazunki If the document is simply missing a number, the reader might reasonably spend ages searching for the missing number and worry about the integrity of the document. If the number is actually being printed somewhere else, then maybe that has a better solution than hiding it in one place and displaying it in another.

Answer (score 2):

The star form `\begin{align*}`...`\end{align*}` suppresses the equation number:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
f_{n}(\beta,\lambda)&= \lambda(1-\lambda/n)^{n-1} \int_{0} ^{1}
g_{n}(\beta,\lambda)d\alpha \\
                     & \leq \lambda(1-\lambda/n)^{n-1}\int_{0}^{1}
g_{n}(\beta,1)d\alpha \\
                     & \leq (1-1/n)^{n-1} \int_{0}^{1} g_{n}(\beta,1)d\alpha
= f_{n}(\beta,1)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

This is a single equation, not a collection of equations that are being aligned, so I would use `equation*`, the `*` suppresses the equation number, and do the alignment with `split`, as below.  This way, if I later find I need to refer to this equation and add a number all I need do is change the outer environment to `equation` and add a `\label` command.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
    f_{n}(\beta,\lambda)
    &= \lambda(1-\lambda/n)^{n-1} \int_{0} ^{1} g_{n}(\beta,\lambda)
    \, d\alpha \\
    & \leq \lambda(1-\lambda/n)^{n-1}\int_{0}^{1} g_{n}(\beta,1)
    \, d\alpha \\
    & \leq (1-1/n)^{n-1} \int_{0}^{1} g_{n}(\beta,1) \, d\alpha
    = f_{n}(\beta,1)
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I have added a standard thin space `\,` before the differentials and would assume you have some punctuation to add at the end of the final line.